# Stuck practicing looping through an array with an error

Tags: java

I am receiving an error in

```
numbers[i] = new int[];
```

> Java array dimension missing.

I am practicing loops through an array and stuff how to resolve.

```java
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {10, 35, 17, 95 ,75, 65, 1012,  1, 99, 69};

        for (int element : numbers) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = new int[];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the size for each array, e.g. `new int[3]`.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Your second for loop doesn't provide an output

Comment: @akuzminykh, when I specify the size in the new array I still get an error "Error: java: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int" - new int[3] for example.

Comment: @KyleMoffett  I was practicing looping through an array to print the values stored. I never made it to the output for the second loop due to the Error

Comment: As Kyle already asked, what exactly are you trying to achieve here? An instantiation of an array should always include the dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first part of the code loops through and prints to screen?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {10, 35, 17, 95 ,75, 65, 1012,  1, 99, 69};

    for (int element : numbers) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
```

Alternatively you could use

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(numbers[i]);
    }
```

You don't need the line

```
numbers[i] = new int[];
```

You've already declared the array and assigned values to it

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you Kyle

Comment: No problem, glad you got sorted!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the array size and its datatype when creating an array in Java.

```
int numbers[] = new int[10];
```

Your loops are correctly written, but the line `numbers[i] = new int[];`, is not needed.

If you want to display the array elements you should implement it as given below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
           System.out.println(numbers[i]); 
        }
```